# How to properly assigning a dynamically create an int and assign it to a dynamic array array with values?

Tags: c++, loops, dynamic-programming, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am working on an assignment for my c++ class where I need to dynamically assign a new int, array, and pointer from another pointer to practice dynamic memory allocation.

At first, I was struggling with creating a new int to provide an int for my new array, but I got it to compile and was wondering if my declarations were correct.

```
int *dmaArray = new int;
*dmaArray = 4;
```

I then took that and put it into a dynamically created array, but I don't know how to declare values of the array as it errors out saying "cannot convert  to int". I did some thinking and I believe it's because it was declared and needs to be initialized at the declaration; I can't because the declaration is already a declaration (new) in itself.

```
int * nodeValues = new int[*dmaArray];
nodeValues[*dmaArray] = {6, 2, 28, 1};
```

A loop wouldn't work to assign values after since the values aren't consecutive or in any pattern. (well, regardless, I would need to use an array because the assignment said so.

Comment: Your code is super confused. Shouldn't they tell you in your class how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: You have some basic understanding problems. I would recommend going through a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/9254539).

Answer (score 1):

This is not how to to declare a `dynamic array` and initialize it:

```
int * nodeValues = new int[*dmaArray];
nodeValues[*dmaArray] = {6, 2, 28, 1};
```

So you declare it this way:

```
int* nodeValues = new int[dmaArray];
```

And to assign values to it use loops or manually:

```
nodeValues[0] = 6;
nodeValues[1] = 2;
nodeValues[2] = 28,
nodeValues[3] = 1;
```

Remember arrays use indexes to read/write its elements as the fact being some sort of data of the same type contiguous to each other in memory.

So if you want to print the array:

```
for(auto i(0); i != dmaArray; ++i)
    std::cout << nodeValues[i] << ", ";
```

Finally you should clean memory dynamically allocated after finishing with it because the compiler doesn't do it for you:

```
delete[] nodeValues;
```

Comment: adding the brace to the end with values some how worked ( int * nodeValues = new int[*dmaArray]{6,5,28,1};)

Comment: What you mean with the ` int[*dmaArray]`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how:

int * nodeValues = new int[*dmaArray]{6,5,28,1};